# Dynamically add set of from as many input in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make form as many as input text, i'm strugling to make a new form into the new div. if input is 3 then make 3 form, if input is 2 then input is just 2.

```
<input type="text" id="CountForm">


<form name="regis" id="regis" method="post" action="">
  <input id="name1" name="name1" />
  <input id="email1" name="email1" />
  <input id="phone1" name="phone1" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to generate dynamic form???

Comment: yes, if input is 5 then add 5 form, but if 3 then just 3 form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this ?

```js
var add = document.getElementById('button');
add.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('CountForm').value);
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  wrapper.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i =1; i<= num; i++){
    var form =
        `<form name="regis" id="regis${i}" method="post" action="">
         <input id="name1" name="name1" />
         <input id="email1" name="email1" />
         <input id="phone1" name="phone1" />
         </form>`
    wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML + form;
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="CountForm" placeholder = "Enter form number">
<input type=button id = "button" value = "add">
<div class = "wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: how do i reset it ? input = 3 then show 3 form, input = 2 then show 2 form.
fixed total form as input does.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this as below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

 var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

 newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
       '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
       '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

 newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


 counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
 if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }

 counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

 var msg = '';
 for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
 }
       alert(msg);
     });
  });
```

```css
 div{
  padding:8px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>jQuery add textbox example</title>
<body>
<h1>jQuery add textbox example</h1>
<body>
<form name="regis" id="regis" method="post" action="">
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
  <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
 </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may Try For this:

```
var add = document.getElementById('button');
add.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('CountForm').value);
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  wrapper.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i =1; i<= num; i++){
    var form =
        `<form name="regis" id="regis${i}" method="post" action="">
         <input id="name1" name="name1" placeholder="please enter name"/>
         <input id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="please enter email" />
         <input id="phone1" name="phone1" placeholder="please enter phone"/>
         <input type="button" id="button12" name="button12" value="submit"/>

         </form>`
    wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML + form;
  }
})
<input type="text" id="CountForm" placeholder = "Enter form number">
<input type=button id = "button" value = "add">
<div class = "wrapper">
</div>
```